# Iterate jira.search_issue list

Tags: python, python-jira

I'm trying to iterate and parse jira key from the list I am receiving by invoking jira.search_issue. http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/jira/client.html#JIRA.search_issues

```
found_issue = jira.search_issues('key=%s and cf[13560] ~ %s' % (new_issue, some_id))
print found_issue
```

prints:

```
[<JIRA Issue: key=u'PRJ-127', id=u'554186'>]
```

Which is what I was looking, however, if I iterate the list with following code

```
for key in jira.search_issues('key=%s and cf[13560] ~ %s' % (new_issue,  some_id)):
    print key
```

I get following result:

```
PRJ-127 - None
```

How to get rid of the "None"?

**EDIT:

Looks like I found the issue, I was getting this "None" stuff with Python 2.6.6. When I updated my python to 2.7.8 I was able to get proper output.

Comment: What data type is found issue?

Comment: This is the type <class 'jira.resources.Issue'>